# Block submit of a form without using JQuery and with input type="submit"

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, submit

I want to block the submit of a form in this condition:

1) Without JQuery;

2) With an input type="submit" (instead of type="button"), because it's the only way (i think) to submit form with Enter Key

Here's my code:

```
<form name="form_ricerca" action="trova_hotels.htm" id="top_form_ricerca" method="post">        
   <fieldset style="margin: 10px;text-align: center;">
     <input id="top_ric_strutt" type="text" name="ricerca" size="40"
     <input onclick="return top_controlla_ricerca();" >
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

and this is the function:

```
function top_controlla_ricerca() {
  var nome_codice = document.getElementById("top_ric_strutt").value;
  SOME_CODE
  if (SOME_CONDITIONS) {
   document.getElementById("top_form_ricerca").submit();
   return true;
  } else {
   alert('MY_ALERT');
   return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of using `onclick` of the button use `onsubmit` event of the form - `<form name="form_ricerca" action="trova_hotels.htm" id="top_form_ricerca" method="post"  onsubmit="return top_controlla_ricerca();">` then `<input type="submit" value="Save" >`

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-to-stop-form-submission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) add onsubmit listener on the form element instead of the input element

```
<form onsubmit="return top_controlla_ricerca();" name="form_ricerca" action="trova_hotels.htm" id="top_form_ricerca" method="post">        
   <fieldset style="margin: 10px;text-align: center;">
     <input id="top_ric_strutt" type="text" name="ricerca" size="40"
     <input type="text" />
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

2.)  remove submit manually inside this function ( submit handler )

```
function top_controlla_ricerca() {
  var nome_codice = document.getElementById("top_ric_strutt").value;
  SOME_CODE
  if (SOME_CONDITIONS) {
   //document.getElementById("top_form_ricerca").submit();  <-- Remove this line
   return true;
  } else {
   alert('MY_ALERT');
   return false;
  }
}
```